# How to access and edit Rprofile?

Tags: r

New to R. How does one access and edit Rprofile?

Comment: Take a look at this description from [Quick R](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html)

Comment: Thanks. I googled edit Rprofile in the past but I hadn't clicked through on link called 'customizing StartUp File' https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html and on your prompting I did and found it helpful.

Comment: Rprofile file is found in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\etc and can be edited by loading it into Notepad++.

Answer (score 70):

On start-up R will look for the R-Profile in the following places:
(https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/set-up.html)

1. R_HOME: the directory in which R is installed.
   Find out where your R_HOME is with the `R.home()` command.
2. HOME, the user’s home directory. Can ask R where this is with, `path.expand("~")`
3. R’s current working directory. This is reported by `getwd()`.

Note although there maybe different R-Profile files R will only use one in a given session. The preference order is:

Current project>Home>R_Home

To create a project-specific start-up script  create a .Rprofile file in the project’s root directory.

You can access and edit the different .Rprofile files via

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile")) # edit .Rprofile in HOME
file.edit(".Rprofile") # edit project specific .Rprofile
```

There is information about the options you can set via

```
help("Rprofile")
```

As mentioned the link above does provide additional details but the points outlined above should show you where the files are and how to access them.