# Function to rename columns in R dataframe with an evolving list

Tags: r

I often prepare summary tables of statistics that I share at work. The tables often contain the same type of data and column headers (e.g. number of bylaw violations, number of units, etc.). I often work with shorthand column names in R data frames ("nbbldg", "nbunits", "nbvl") or other column names inherited from imported tables. Here's an example:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    DESCRIPTION_TXT_BLW = c(
      "Missing plumbing fixture",
      "Improperly installed heating unit",
      "Loose or damaged siding",
      "Peeling paint"
    ),
    DESCR_UNIT = c("Apartment", "Apartment", "Common area", "Common area"),
    nbvl = as.integer(c(12, 4, 76, 4))
  )
```

I then translate the column names into their "readable" counterparts before exporting to csv through the following function (example list provided) :

```
changecolnames<-function (df, codetotext) 
{
  lapply(names(df), function(x) {
    if (x %in% names(codetotext)) {
      codetotext[[x]]
    }
    else {
      x
    }
  })
}

readablecolnames <-
      list(
        "DESCR_UNIT" = "Description of unit",
        "DESCRIPTION_TXT_BLW" = "Description of bylaw violation",
        "nbvl" = "Number of bylaw violations"
      )

names(df)<-changecolnames(df, readablecolnames)
```

So far, I have project specific lists which allow to me convert the columns names. I would like to aggregate the disparate lists into a global one accessible from any R project (in RStudio) and keep adding to it. My objective is to avoid creating a list in each project, and instead refer to a sort of easy-to-update master "library". What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: You could have a central R file that contains your list of names and `source` it in each project.

Comment: To make the shorthand/readable name pairs easier to enter as I grow my "library", could the file I source be a csv that then gets translated to a named list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is have a central R file that contains this list of names and then `source` it to load it into each project.

If you'd rather keep the name pairs in a `.csv` file, this R file could instead generate the name list from a single file instead of holding it itself:

**name_pairs.csv:**

```
short_name,full_name
DESCR_UNIT,Description of unit
DESCRIPTION_TXT_BLW,Description of bylaw violation
nbvl,Number of bylaw violations
```

**load_name_pairs.R:**

```
name_pairs <- read.table('~/Desktop/test/name_pairs.csv', sep = ',',
                         header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

readablecolnames <- name_pairs$full_name
names(readablecolnames) <- name_pairs$short_name
rm(name_pairs)
```

**At the start of your R project:**

```
source('~/Desktop/test/load_name_pairs.r')
readablecolnames


           DESCR_UNIT              DESCRIPTION_TXT_BLW                             nbvl 
"Description of unit" "Description of bylaw violation"     "Number of bylaw violations"
```

As you can see, by using `source` on `load_name_pairs.r`, all the code in the `sourced` file is run and objects are i,ported into the `sourcing` environment. So with just one line in your project file, you can load and parse a central `.csv` file and access the results in your project.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. For added convenience, could I insert the "source" code within the changecolnames (in my question) function ?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. If `source` is run with the default `local=FALSE` argument, sourced objects will be loaded into the global environment, so it doesn't matter if you call it from a function.

Comment: I added the code `source('~/Desktop/test/load_name_pairs.r')` to my .Rprofile file ([how to edit Rprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819910/10047977)), to load the name pair table automatically when I launch RStudio.