# cannot install packages from github - uninterpretable error message

Tags: r, github

I cannot install any R packages from Github, though I've done this several times before. I've tried this with both R Versions 3.5.0 and 3.5.1.

Attempting to install "https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/bookdown-master.zip" using:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
githubinstall::githubinstall("bookdown")
```

or downloading and trying to load locally...

```
install_local("/Users/Brian/Documents/bookdown-master.zip")
```

always gives me the error message

```
Error in readLines(f) : 
(converted from warning) incomplete final line found on '/Users/Brian/.Rprofile'
```

I've tried other workarounds, as well, but all roads seem to lead to this error message, and I can't find anything that would tell me what it relates to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there's something formatted incorrectly in your Rprofile file. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46819684/5325862) another question, albeit a closed one, with some links that might help

Comment: Thanks Camille. I was out of ideas. That info helped me solve my problem. I didn't realize that .Rprofile was something that I could edit - but apparently I had done it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error was the result of a previous edit that I had made to .Rprofile while creating a website with the `blogdown` package. I didn't remember doing this, but clearly it was interfering with package downloads.

After running `file.edit(".Rprofile")`, deleting the single line it contained, and then restarting R, packages are installing again.