# increasing max.print does not always work in R and neither does global options for lsmeans()

Tags: r, row, lsmeans

Half of the time, without pattern, I get rows omitted from the output even though I increase max.print and the global options in R studio. Details below:

I am running an lmer model on large datasets (more than 100,000 observations of 14 variables) with packages: lme4, lmerTest, tidyverse, lsmeans

I have several datasets that I run separately, but the datasets are not different in design from each other and they all originated from the same mother dataset. I just removed certain rows in each dataset to answer different questions. Variables in each dataset include hour, location, date, depth, temperature and transformed depth to meet assumptions.

For some reason after I run the lsmeans() function to get pairwise comparisons, half of the time there are rows omitted:
[reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 110 rows]

example code:

`ft.model = lmer(dep.variable ~ fixed.factor + (1|random.factor), data = dataset)`

`anova(ft.model)`

`plot(ft.model, main = "residuals/fitted ft.model")`

`lsmeans(ft.model, pairwise~fixed.factor, adjust = "Tukey", max.print = 9999)`

So it looks like this with some of my variables:

`ft.hrdepth = lmer(depth ~ hr + (1|FishID), data = all)`

`anova(ft.hrdepth)`

`plot(ft.hrdepth, main = "residuals/fitted ft.hrdepth")`

`lsmeans(ft.hrdepth, pairwise~hr, adjust = "Tukey", max.print = 9999)`

I have tried adding the max.print argument and increasing to 10000, 10000000, 9999, 99999999, Inf, and other combos.
I have also gone into RStudio settings and changed the limit of lines displayed to similar numbers: Tools > Global Options > Code > Display > Limit length of lines displayed in console is: 1000000

I have also made lsmeans into an object and used the print() function to print the output or just the contrasts, but still no luck:

`pws = lsmeans(ft.model, pairwise~fixed.factor, adjust = "Tukey", max.print = 9999)`

`print(pws)`

`pwss = pws[[contrasts]]`

`print(pwss)`

I have tried repeatedly with the same exact dataset and different datasets, and see absolutely no pattern as to why it omits rows sometimes and doesn't omit rows sometimes.

I have no fix to view the lsmeans output in the console or at the bottom of the R Markdown file I have. (Note I also get the same result when I use an R script file instead of R mardown file = only 1/2 the time do I get all the rows). Please help! The only way I can guarantee seeing all the rows is by exporting the lsmeans contrasts output to a csv file, which is extremely inefficient and not helpful since I also ideally knit all my results to a single document:

`pws = lsmeans(ft.model, pairwise~fixed.factor, adjust = "Tukey", max.print = 9999)`

`pwss = pws[[contrasts]]`

`write.csv(pwss,file = "pwss.csv")`

FYI, I use RStudio Version 1.1.419 and R i386 3.4.3
My computer is an HP windows 10 Pro 64-bit operating system

example dataset:

structure(list(X = c(1L, 15L, 20L, 26L, 35L, 44L, 55L, 66L, 77L, 
88L, 99L, 1111L, 44444L, 77777L, 8888L, 999L, 2222L, 4444L, 55555L, 
66666L, 777L, 88888L, 99999L, 11111L, 57890L, 23456L, 9675L, 
129873L, 22222L, 333L, 5555L, 123434L, 99944L, 88833L, 77744L, 
66655L, 55544L, 44433L, 33322L, 22211L, 134534L, 111111L, 121111L, 
131111L, 141111L, 151111L, 161111L, 123111L, 33444L, 5566L, 6677L, 
9988L, 33888L, 87878L, 148483L, 139847L, 34231L, 34200L), OrigDate = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 18L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 10L, 7L, 23L, 9L, 1L, 
4L, 22L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
23L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 22L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 17L, 26L, 25L, 
11L, 11L), .Label = c("10/01/2012", "10/02/2012", "10/03/2012", 
"10/04/2012", "10/05/2012", "10/06/2012", "10/07/2012", "10/08/2012", 
"10/14/2012", "10/15/2012", "10/21/2012", "10/27/2012", "11/02/2012", 
"11/03/2012", "11/08/2012", "11/15/2012", "11/19/2012", "11/20/2012", 
"11/25/2012", "11/29/2012", "12/03/2012", "12/04/2012", "12/08/2012", 
"12/10/2012", "12/13/2012", "12/17/2012", "12/18/2012", "12/23/2012"
), class = "factor"), OrigTime = structure(c(1L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
9L, 11L, 13L, 18L, 22L, 25L, 27L, 32L, 47L, 3L, 2L, 52L, 33L, 
40L, 39L, 21L, 4L, 45L, 48L, 7L, 28L, 14L, 16L, 55L, 23L, 44L, 
49L, 19L, 30L, 24L, 41L, 15L, 29L, 42L, 20L, 10L, 17L, 26L, 31L, 
38L, 56L, 36L, 50L, 43L, 57L, 51L, 46L, 35L, 12L, 37L, 54L, 34L, 
58L, 53L), .Label = c("00:03:39", "00:10:58", "00:31:07", "00:41:09", 
"01:24:09", "01:48:18", "02:10:49", "02:17:49", "03:33:44", "04:41:53", 
"04:47:35", "05:13:35", "05:52:04", "06:04:16", "06:27:49", "06:45:23", 
"06:57:49", "07:03:07", "07:03:26", "07:19:39", "07:25:02", "08:12:43", 
"08:37:03", "08:44:48", "09:27:02", "09:30:58", "10:41:49", "10:52:47", 
"11:09:06", "11:10:01", "11:12:46", "11:15:04", "11:34:46", "11:59:42", 
"12:02:58", "12:36:34", "12:39:42", "13:20:47", "13:45:05", "13:50:05", 
"13:51:44", "14:04:15", "14:47:51", "14:51:57", "15:23:14", "15:37:53", 
"15:49:09", "16:08:00", "16:10:44", "16:37:25", "17:34:17", "18:17:16", 
"19:34:03", "20:23:36", "20:40:22", "21:20:51", "21:27:49", "22:44:33"
), class = "factor"), OrigDateTime = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 26L, 35L, 31L, 8L, 
19L, 27L, 39L, 47L, 2L, 40L, 43L, 34L, 45L, 18L, 33L, 58L, 17L, 
7L, 28L, 56L, 42L, 41L, 36L, 46L, 38L, 25L, 24L, 16L, 48L, 44L, 
54L, 57L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 21L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 
49L, 22L, 20L), .Label = c("10/1/2012 0:03:39", "10/1/2012 0:41:09", 
"10/1/2012 1:24:09", "10/1/2012 1:48:18", "10/1/2012 10:41:49", 
"10/1/2012 11:15:04", "10/1/2012 14:51:57", "10/1/2012 18:17:16", 
"10/1/2012 2:17:49", "10/1/2012 3:33:44", "10/1/2012 4:47:35", 
"10/1/2012 5:52:04", "10/1/2012 7:03:07", "10/1/2012 8:12:43", 
"10/1/2012 9:27:02", "10/14/2012 4:41:53", "10/14/2012 8:37:03", 
"10/15/2012 6:04:16", "10/2/2012 11:34:46", "10/21/2012 19:34:03", 
"10/21/2012 21:27:49", "10/21/2012 22:44:33", "10/21/2012 5:13:35", 
"10/21/2012 7:19:39", "10/27/2012 14:04:15", "10/27/2012 15:49:09", 
"10/3/2012 13:50:05", "10/4/2012 16:10:44", "10/4/2012 17:34:17", 
"10/5/2012 15:37:53", "10/6/2012 0:10:58", "10/7/2012 12:02:58", 
"10/7/2012 6:45:23", "10/8/2012 2:10:49", "11/15/2012 0:31:07", 
"11/15/2012 13:51:44", "11/19/2012 12:39:42", "11/2/2012 11:09:06", 
"11/2/2012 13:45:05", "11/20/2012 15:23:14", "11/20/2012 8:44:48", 
"11/25/2012 11:10:01", "11/25/2012 16:08:00", "11/29/2012 9:30:58", 
"11/3/2012 10:52:47", "11/8/2012 6:27:49", "11/8/2012 7:25:02", 
"12/10/2012 6:57:49", "12/13/2012 11:59:42", "12/13/2012 21:20:51", 
"12/17/2012 20:23:36", "12/18/2012 12:36:34", "12/23/2012 16:37:25", 
"12/3/2012 11:12:46", "12/4/2012 14:47:51", "12/4/2012 7:03:26", 
"12/8/2012 13:20:47", "12/8/2012 20:40:22"), class = "factor"), 
    TimeSerial = c(41183.0025347222, 41183.0584375, 41183.0752083333, 
    41183.0957060185, 41183.1484259259, 41183.1997106482, 41183.2444907407, 
    41183.2938310185, 41183.3421643519, 41183.3937731481, 41183.4457060185, 
    41183.4687962963, 41209.6591319444, 41228.0216087963, 41188.0076157407, 
    41183.7619907407, 41184.4824768519, 41185.5764467593, 41215.572974537, 
    41221.3090509259, 41183.0285763889, 41233.6411342593, 41238.6722222222, 
    41190.0908449074, 41216.4533217593, 41197.252962963, 41189.2815162037, 
    41251.8613657407, 41196.3590625, 41183.6194097222, 41186.6741203704, 
    41247.2940509259, 41238.4652893519, 41233.3644444444, 41228.5775925926, 
    41221.2693171296, 41215.4646527778, 41209.5862847222, 41203.3053125, 
    41196.1957523148, 41253.290150463, 41242.3965046296, 41246.4671990741, 
    41251.556099537, 41256.8894791667, 41261.5253935185, 41266.6926504629, 
    41247.6165625, 41203.8943171296, 41186.7321412037, 41187.6513078704, 
    41189.5020601851, 41203.2177662037, 41232.5275694444, 41260.8497222222, 
    41256.4997916667, 41203.9476041667, 41203.8153125), DateNum = c(41183L, 
    41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 
    41183L, 41183L, 41183L, 41209L, 41228L, 41188L, 41183L, 41184L, 
    41185L, 41215L, 41221L, 41183L, 41233L, 41238L, 41190L, 41216L, 
    41197L, 41189L, 41251L, 41196L, 41183L, 41186L, 41247L, 41238L, 
    41233L, 41228L, 41221L, 41215L, 41209L, 41203L, 41196L, 41253L, 
    41242L, 41246L, 41251L, 41256L, 41261L, 41266L, 41247L, 41203L, 
    41186L, 41187L, 41189L, 41203L, 41232L, 41260L, 41256L, 41203L, 
    41203L), TimeNum = c(0.0025347222, 0.0584375, 0.0752083333, 
    0.0957060185, 0.1484259259, 0.1997106482, 0.2444907407, 0.2938310185, 
    0.3421643519, 0.3937731481, 0.4457060185, 0.4687962963, 0.6591319444, 
    0.0216087963, 0.0076157407, 0.7619907407, 0.4824768519, 0.5764467593, 
    0.572974537, 0.3090509259, 0.0285763889, 0.6411342593, 0.6722222222, 
    0.0908449074, 0.4533217593, 0.252962963, 0.2815162037, 0.8613657407, 
    0.3590625, 0.6194097222, 0.6741203704, 0.2940509259, 0.4652893519, 
    0.3644444444, 0.5775925926, 0.2693171296, 0.4646527778, 0.5862847222, 
    0.3053125, 0.1957523148, 0.290150463, 0.3965046296, 0.4671990741, 
    0.556099537, 0.8894791667, 0.5253935185, 0.692650463, 0.6165625, 
    0.8943171296, 0.7321412037, 0.6513078704, 0.5020601852, 0.2177662037, 
    0.5275694444, 0.8497222222, 0.4997916667, 0.9476041667, 0.8153125
    ), depth = c(19.34, 19.34, 19.12, 18.46, 19.34, 19.34, 19.34, 
    19.12, 18.9, 19.12, 18.02, 20.88, 21.1, 20.44, 20.22, 20.44, 
    17.36, 18.9, 20, 17.8, 18.9, 17.36, 19.34, 16.92, 20.22, 
    20.22, 20, 9.89, 19.56, 18.68, 20, 11.9, 20.22, 19.56, 21.1, 
    16.7, 20, 21.1, 19.56, 16.92, 20.22, 18.24, 17.36, 20.66, 
    10.3, 20.88, 19.34, 21.32, 16.26, 17.58, 18.46, 20, 18.46, 
    17.58, 9.45, 10.8, 18.68, 18.46), FishID = c(5593L, 5593L, 
    5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 5593L, 
    7510L, 7513L, 7508L, 7510L, 7509L, 7501L, 7508L, 7511L, 5593L, 
    7508L, 7501L, 5593L, 7502L, 7513L, 7501L, 7501L, 5593L, 7508L, 
    6747L, 7501L, 7514L, 5593L, 7501L, 7505L, 5593L, 7511L, 7513L, 
    5593L, 7508L, 6747L, 7510L, 7512L, 7509L, 7508L, 7501L, 7496L, 
    7510L, 5593L, 7501L, 7501L, 7503L, 7502L, 7514L, 5593L, 5593L, 
    7508L, 7508L), Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "PM", class = "factor"), 
    Temp = c(28.7, 28.7, 28.7, 28.7, 28.7, 28.7, 28.7, 28.6, 
    28.6, 28.6, 28.6, 28.6, 27, 24.1, 28, 28.6, 28.6, 28.2, 25.3, 
    25.8, 28.7, 22.6, 22.7, 27.5, 25.5, 27.6, 27.7, 22.5, 27.8, 
    28.6, 27.9, 21.6, 22.6, 22.6, 23.7, 26, 25.7, 27, 27.9, 27.8, 
    22.7, 22, 21.7, 22.4, 20.8, 21.4, 21.8, 21.6, 27.8, 28, 27.8, 
    27.7, 27.9, 22.6, 21.6, 20.7, 27.8, 27.7), hr = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 
    19L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 16L, 17L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 21L, 
    9L, 15L, 17L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 14L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 
    10L, 12L, 14L, 22L, 13L, 17L, 15L, 22L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 6L, 
    13L, 21L, 12L, 23L, 20L), .Label = c("01:00:00", "02:00:00", 
    "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
    "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", 
    "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", 
    "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", 
    "23:00:00"), class = "factor"), sqrtdepth = c(4.3977266854592, 
    4.3977266854592, 4.37264222181509, 4.29651021178817, 4.3977266854592, 
    4.3977266854592, 4.3977266854592, 4.37264222181509, 4.34741302385683, 
    4.37264222181509, 4.24499705535823, 4.56946386351834, 4.59347363114234, 
    4.52106182218293, 4.49666543118342, 4.52106182218293, 4.16653333119993, 
    4.34741302385683, 4.47213595499958, 4.2190046219458, 4.34741302385683, 
    4.16653333119993, 4.3977266854592, 4.11339276024063, 4.49666543118342, 
    4.49666543118342, 4.47213595499958, 3.14483703870328, 4.4226688774992, 
    4.32203655699486, 4.47213595499958, 3.44963766213207, 4.49666543118342, 
    4.4226688774992, 4.59347363114234, 4.08656334834051, 4.47213595499958, 
    4.59347363114234, 4.4226688774992, 4.11339276024063, 4.49666543118342, 
    4.27083130081252, 4.16653333119993, 4.5453272709454, 3.20936130717624, 
    4.56946386351834, 4.3977266854592, 4.61735855224608, 4.03236903073119, 
    4.19285105864733, 4.29651021178817, 4.47213595499958, 4.29651021178817, 
    4.19285105864733, 3.07408522978788, 3.286335345031, 4.32203655699486, 
    4.29651021178817), sqdepth = c(374.0356, 374.0356, 365.5744, 
    340.7716, 374.0356, 374.0356, 374.0356, 365.5744, 357.21, 
    365.5744, 324.7204, 435.9744, 445.21, 417.7936, 408.8484, 
    417.7936, 301.3696, 357.21, 400, 316.84, 357.21, 301.3696, 
    374.0356, 286.2864, 408.8484, 408.8484, 400, 97.8121, 382.5936, 
    348.9424, 400, 141.61, 408.8484, 382.5936, 445.21, 278.89, 
    400, 445.21, 382.5936, 286.2864, 408.8484, 332.6976, 301.3696, 
    426.8356, 106.09, 435.9744, 374.0356, 454.5424, 264.3876, 
    309.0564, 340.7716, 400, 340.7716, 309.0564, 89.3025, 116.64, 
    348.9424, 340.7716), cudepth = c(7233.848504, 7233.848504, 
    6989.782528, 6290.643736, 7233.848504, 7233.848504, 7233.848504, 
    6989.782528, 6751.269, 6989.782528, 5851.461608, 9103.145472, 
    9393.931, 8539.701184, 8266.914648, 8539.701184, 5231.776256, 
    6751.269, 8000, 5639.752, 6751.269, 5231.776256, 7233.848504, 
    4843.965888, 8266.914648, 8266.914648, 8000, 967.361669, 
    7483.530816, 6518.244032, 8000, 1685.159, 8266.914648, 7483.530816, 
    9393.931, 4657.463, 8000, 9393.931, 7483.530816, 4843.965888, 
    8266.914648, 6068.404224, 5231.776256, 8818.423496, 1092.727, 
    9103.145472, 7233.848504, 9690.843968, 4298.942376, 5433.211512, 
    6290.643736, 8000, 6290.643736, 5433.211512, 843.908625, 
    1259.712, 6518.244032, 6290.643736)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-58L))

I would love any input!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if we could run all the code you provided (without much editing) to get the error you are.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Could you post a sample of the data for us to work with? You can use `dput()`. It could also just be fabricated data.

Comment: Hi mickey, thanks. will post now

Comment: Just an inclusion of some data. Your initial four lines were fine, but if you include the `dataset` object used in `lmer`, it will just help us all be on the same page.

Comment: Yep, just finished making a sample dataset. I ran the sample, and it worked on RStudio, but again didn't include all the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `max.print` option with

```
options('max.print' = 100000)   # or whatever value you want
getOption('max.print')
[1] 100000
```

When you do `lsmeans(stuff, max.print = 10000)`, you're actually passing the argument (not option) of `max.print` to other functions in the `emmeans` package. That's what is meant by the `...` argument for `lsmeans` (see `?lsmeans::lsmeans`). Whatever `max.print` is passed to in this case doesn't change the value in `getOption('max.print')`. You could just as well do `lsmeans(stuff, some_random_arg = 'whatever i want')` and not have any error returned, but is completely meaningless.

You can make the change carry over from session to session by modifying your Rprofile. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile) might help getting you going in the right direction so you don't have to keep changing the `max.print` option everytime you start up a new R session. There may be an alternate way of doing it through RStudio, but I'm not familiar enough with the platform to help with that.

Comment: Thank you! It works for now. If I have additional problems, I will let you know