# Set a specific language for dates permanently in R

Tags: r, date

I want to permanently set the default language of date in R to english. Now every time I start a new R session I have greek as default language even though I use:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
[1] "2019-Ιουλ-29"
```

I found that I have to use something like:

```
.First <- function() {
   Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
   }
```

but I cannot understand where to put this. Anybody knows the steps?

Comment: Have a look here - https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: Another ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile

Comment: I made this work by modifying this file but when I deploy my shiny app in shinyapps.io its greek again. Strange!