# How can I modify the startup message in R? Where is the code with this message?

Tags: r, startup, ubuntu-20.04

I suppose that it will be a file with the code containing the startup message.

Comment: If you mean RStudio then see: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf and https://www.roelpeters.be/what-is-the-rprofile-file/

Comment: @SteveM. I meant R. I saw profile file but this does not contain startup messages, and the function of the second links is just to suppress specific warnings. Anyway thanks for the info

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify the current R text, or add some yourself?
For packages, look at the file `zzz.R`. Otherwise you could use `cat` in your .Rprofile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a personal startup message for R (which also will show in RStudio) by adding a line with `message()` in the `.Rprofile`.

In my case, the `.Rprofile` is in "My Documents" under Windows and is edited with the free tool Notepad++.

At the end of the file I have a line

```
### KoenV: Illustrate setting R startup message
message("I have changed my message")
```

The following appears when I start `R`

[image]

You can read more about accessing and editing this file in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile).