# Ruuning app without having the need to type library(devtools) into the consoles Rstudios

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a app.r script written by one of my ex colleague and he left the company quite a while back.

In order for me to open the app , I will have to type these 3 commands into Rstudios console before I can use the runApp/shiny::runApp() function.

1. library(devtools)
2. document()
3. options(shiny.launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyWindowExternal)

I would like to ask if there is any code that I could add into my colleague's app.R

I am trying to reduce the number of console code I have to type  remove the need to do so before i use the runApp/shiny:runApp() function

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What if you create another script that has these 4 commands in, and just run that? If you're on linux, this is fairly straightforward by running `Rscript ./scriptname.R`.

Comment: Thank you for replying~

I am trying to run this on windows OS. Is there an alternative solution other than creating another script and run it?

Comment: There are, but i wouldn't consider them "clean", like modifying the `.Rprofile` file.

Comment: Ill give this a go and see if i can make it easier for other users in my lab to follow the instructions. Thanks for the replies haha

Actually , could you give me a direction on where could I learn about modifying the Rprofile and adding these commands line in the file to get it working?

Comment: If you're really serious about distributing the shiny app (but not willing to host it, not even internally), you might want to have a look at Docker and how you can use it to package a shiny app (and possibly data).

As for the .Rprofile editing, have you tried searching the internet or seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile)?

Comment: Apologies , I am rather new to R language and I have only recently read about Rprofiling. I am grateful to receive your reply and will have a look at your link and check more about profiling of R online .

Thanks again