# How do you fix "Warning message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork)"

Tags: r

I installed R and R studio for the first time,
and whenever I open R studio, I get this warning message:

`Warning message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/uSER/Dropbox/? PC (LAPTOP-P9GEUM65)/Documents": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

- I thought maybe the Dropbox is the problem so I even deleted Dropbox from my laptop,
- uninstalled and reinstalled both R and R studio several times, but it still shows up

Could anyone help me solve this problem? I need to start doing real things on R but I'm stuck at the beginning,,

Comment: Check your `$HOME/.Rprofile`. If you're running a project in a dropbox directory, don't do that, run it out of a local-only no-syncing directory.

Comment: How do I perform the $HOME/.Rprofile? where is it located?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile